# Can't 'Edit' an asset in the Assets module

Tags: assets

We have number of sites running the P&T Assets add-on. All are working fine and allow us to 'Edit' the properties of a file or image when right-clicking on the asset. However, we've just started a new build **using EE: v2.7.3 and Assets: 2.2.2** and for some reason, choosing 'Edit' when right-clicking doesn't display the edit pop-up. We can successfully choose 'View', 'Rename' and 'Delete'...but choosing 'Edit' does nothing?

I've tried in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. All fail. I'm guessing it's a permissions issue? However, I'm logged in as 'Super Admin'.

Any thoughts?

Gary

Comment: Any useful error messages in the firebug javascript console?

Comment: Ah, good thinking. Yes, there are errors. Page renders without errors but as soon as I right click on an asset and choose 'Edit', I get the following:

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message:  DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (@1.392048775E+12) at position 11 (5): Unexpected character
Filename: libraries/Localize.php
Line Number: 299`

Also assets.min.js is throwing up:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.hud.$hud')`

I'm not sure what this means?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting support@pixelandtonic.com and pointing them to this page - I'm sure they can be of assistance.

Comment: Thanks. Have emailed them this morning. Will post findings back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Andris @ P&T, the issue was caused by a bug in Assets. A fix will be included in the next version of Assets.

> I fixed it for your install and this fix will be included in the next Assets version, so you don't have to worry about updating, unless you update to Assets 2.2.4, which is currently the freshest version out there and it does not include this fix. If you do and this error comes back, let me know - I'll fix it again :)